# Error en JQuery

Tags: jquery, html5, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-validate

Estoy elaborando un proyecto usando C# en Visual Studio 2019, mediante MVC ASP.NET....
El proyecto lleva un formulario en donde el usuario de la página debe crear una cuenta para poder ingresar a ella, al ser un formulario de creación de cuenta, valido usando JQuery Validate, que los campos cumplan con las especificaciones necesarias por ejemplo, cantidad de caracteres, tipos de mail, que  no vayan campos vacíos, etc...
Las validaciones que hice incluye una función en donde por medio de rules indico si son requeridos o nó, cantidad de caracteres, etc... Y la otra función establece los mensajes que deben de salir al momento de validar los campos del formulario. Al momento de hacer la prueba del formulario en el navegador el formulario envió los datos de forma correcta pero permitió en que se enviarán campos vacíos, volví a probarlo pero esta vez con todos los campos del formulario vacíos para ver si realmente JQUERY Validate hacia su trabajo y al hacerlo me di cuenta de que los campos no se validaban, no aparecían los mensajes que había creado....
Por lo que procedí a actualizar las versiones de JQuery y JQuery Validate y a crear un nuevo formulario mas pequeño para cuestiones de pruebas y obtuve el mismo resultado...
Este es el código de la vista:

```
    <h2>Prueba Jquery</h2>
    <div class="container">
        <form action="" method="post" class="form-group" id="FormUsuario">
            <label>Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" name="Nombre" id="Nombre" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" />
            <br />
            <label>Primer apellido</label>
            <input type="text" name="Apellido_1" id="Apellido_1" class="form-control" placeholder="Primer Apellido" />
            <br />
            <label>Correo electrónico</label>
            <input type="email" name="E_mail" id="E_mail" class="form-control" placeholder="Correo Electrónico" />
            <br />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="btnCrearCuenta" id="btnCrearCuenta" value="Crear Cuenta">Crear cuenta</button>
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    </form>
</div>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Ejecuta las varidaciones para el formulario (1.10.2)
    $(document).ready(function () {
        EstableceMensajesJqueryValidate();
        EstableceValidaciones();
    });

    function EstableceValidaciones() {
        $("#FormUsuario").validate({
            rules: {
                Nombre: {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength: 50
                },
                Apellido_1: {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength: 50
                },
                E_mail: {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength: 50,
                    email: true
                }
            }
        });
    }
    function EstableceMensajesJqueryValidate() {
        $.extend($.validator.messages, {
            maxlength: $.validator.format("Favor ingrese {0} o menos caracteres"),
            minlength: $.validator.format("Favor ingrese al menos {0} caracteres"),
            required: $.validator.format("Valor Requerido"),
            url: "Debe ingresar una dirección web válida",
            rangelength: $.validator.format("Favor ingrese un valor entre {0} y {1} caracteres de longitud"),
            range: $.validator.format("Favor ingrese un valor entre {0} y {1}"),
            max: $.validator.format("Favor ingrese un valor menor o igual a: {0}"),
            min: $.validator.format("Favor ingrese un valor mayor o igual a: {0}"),
            number: "Favor ingrese un número válido",
            digits: "Favor ingrese solo números",
            email: "Favor ingrese una dirección de correo electrónico válida",
            accept: $.validator.format("Favor seleccione un formato válido {0}"),
            extension: $.validator.format("Favor seleccione un formato válido {0}"),
            require_from_group: $.validator.format("Ingrese al menos uno de estos valores"),
            equalTo: $.validator.format("Los contraseñas no coinciden")

        });
    }
    </script>
```

Después de revisar la ventana de salida del depurador vi este mensaje:

> jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'messages' of
> undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'messages' of undefined
> at EstableceMensajesJqueryValidate (https://localhost:44355/Usuario/PruebaJquery:85:24)
> at HTMLDocument. (https://localhost:44355/Usuario/PruebaJquery:61:3)
> at mightThrow (https://localhost:44355/Scripts/jquery-3.6.0.js:3766:29)
> at process (https://localhost:44355/Scripts/jquery-3.6.0.js:3834:12) undefined
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'messages' of undefined

Espero que me puedan ayudar a resolver el problema, Gracias de antemano,saludos!

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si comentas la llamada a `EstableceMensajesJqueryValidate()` y dejas solo la llamada a `EstableceValidaciones()`?

Comment: No pasa nada, no sale nada...

Comment: ¿Y el navegador si está descargando el script `jquery.validate.js` sin problemas?

Comment: Disculpen la ignorancia, pero como me doy cuenta de eso, usando F12?

Comment: Suponiendo que usas chrome, tiene una pestaña llamada _Sources_ donde puedes ver todos los _fuentes_ que el navegador ha obtenido, entre ellos, los scripts de javascript.

Comment: Ya revise la pestaña de Sources, y en la carpeta de scripts solo salen los archivos jquery-3.6.0.js,bootstrap.js y modernizr-2.8.3.js y también aparece el mismo error de javascript y jquery...

Comment: Me temo entonces que no se está viendo el código del validate en en el navegador, quizás tienes mala la dirección del script o haya otro problema. Comenzaría asegurándome por ver que al poner la ruta completa en la dirección del navegador, se sirva el archivo.

Comment: Voy a revisarlo bien para ver que tal, estaré avisando...Gracias!!

Comment: Hola, ya revise la dirección del script en el navegador y el navegador muestra el archivo.... Puede que sea un error en el código de JQuery o Javascript?